# jQuery Droppable photo manager with clone to trash rather than move to trash option

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

Can you please guide me to the right path in modifying the droppable photo manager example? I want to clone image from Gallery section to Trash instead of moving the image from Gallery to Trash. It is now doing *cut and paste*. What I want is *copy and paste*. I'm using jQueryUI 1.10.2

http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#photo-manager

jQuery UI (Shopping Cart) has almost this functionality but didn't have the DELETE and RECYCLE options.

http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#shopping-cart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `deleteImage` code to not move the droppable element but rather clone it an move it to the "trash", though I guess you'll need to call it something other than `deleteImage`

```
function deleteImage( $item ) {
    var $list = $( "ul", $trash ).length ?
      $( "ul", $trash ) :
      $( "<ul class='gallery ui-helper-reset'/>" ).appendTo( $trash ),
      $clone = $item.clone();

    $clone.find( "a.ui-icon-trash" ).remove();
    $clone.append( recycle_icon ).hide().appendTo( $list ).fadeIn(function() {
      $clone
        .animate({ width: "48px" })
        .find( "img" )
          .animate({ height: "36px" });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, it works the way I want :)
And of course function name will be changed for this case, any how
When I click on (Recycle Image) it shows (Page Not Found), instead of Removing the image that I click on its Recycle option :(